# Phpmailer html emails in plain only

Tags: html, email, phpmailer

I am trying to send an html email using phpmailer. The email always sends but is always in plain text. The email account I am sending it too receives other emails that are html so the problem isn't there. My last try was with this most basic example from the phpmailer site but the received text is plain. Can anyone see what I am missing or doing wrong?

```
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'Your Name');
$mail->addAddress('my_email_address@mine.com', 'My Friend');
$mail->Subject = 'An HTML Message';
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Body = 'Hello, <b>my friend</b>! This message uses HTML!';

if(!$mail->send()) {
  echo 'Message was not sent.';
  echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo 'Message has been sent.';
}
```

Comment: Can you post the source of the received message?

Answer (score 1):

```
$mail->Body = 'Hello, <b>my friend</b>! This message uses HTML!';
$mail->isHTML(true);
```

Call `$mail->isHTML(true);` after you've called the body!

If this doesn't work, try using `$mail->msgHTML();`

Example:

```
$mail->msgHTML('Hello, <b>my friend</b>! This message uses HTML!');
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I made that change but the received email is still plain.

Comment: Sorry that didn't work! Will look further into it to try and help! @user3052443

Comment: The $mail->msgHTML command worked. Thank you so much. I've spent hours on trying to get this to work.

Comment: No worries! Glad I could help! @user3052443